# Testcontainers oracle DB

Tags: spring, oracle, testcontainers, oracle-xe, testcontainers-junit5

I'm trying to setup a integration test Using Testcontainers and Oracle-xe database.
I'm getting the error below:

application.properties entry:spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver

```
Driver org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver claims to not accept jdbcUrl, jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:55802/xepdb1
```

My Test extension:

```
public class OracleDBContainerExtension implements AfterAllCallback, BeforeAllCallback {
      private OracleContainer container;

      @Override
      public void beforeAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        // gvenzl/oracle-xe:18.4.0-slim
        container = new OracleContainer();
        container.start();
        container.waitingFor(
            Wait.forListeningPort().withStartupTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(180L)));
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.url", container.getJdbcUrl());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.password", container.getPassword());
        System.setProperty("spring.datasource.username", container.getUsername());
      }

      @Override
      public void afterAll(ExtensionContext context) {
        container.stop();
      }
    }
```

test:

```
    @Testcontainers
    @SpringBootTest
    @ExtendWith(OracleDBContainerExtension.class)
    public class HeroRepositoryTest {
      @Autowired
      private HeroRepository repositoryUnderTest;

      @Test
      public void shouldReturnHeroesSuccessfully() {
        System.out.println("junit version: " + Version.id());
        List<Hero> heroes = repositoryUnderTest.allHeros();
        assertThat(heroes).hasSize(1);
        repositoryUnderTest.addHero(new Hero("bb", "bb"));
        Collection<Hero> heroesAfter = repositoryUnderTest.allHeros();
        assertThat(heroesAfter).hasSize(2);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Check out https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/oraclexe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs about [Testcontainers JDBC support](https://www.testcontainers.org/modules/databases/jdbc/) --

> If you're using the JDBC URL support, there is no need to instantiate
> an instance of the container - Testcontainers will do it
> automagically.

In other words, one should either use the `ContainerDatabaseDriver` and the JDBC URL with `tc:` prefix or a container instance with `getJdbcUrl()` and the original driver (or let the system detect the driver for you).

So if you make this a normal Oracle driver:
`spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.testcontainers.jdbc.ContainerDatabaseDriver`, it should work.

Comment: Thank you. What a coincidence, started to watch your youtube video about it this morning!